# Zsh alias not working as in bash

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I use this alias in my `.bashrc` but doesn't seem to work in `zsh` using `.zshrc`. Other aliases I use are working fine so I know the `.zshrc` is sourcing other aliases.

```
alias rubydev3="cd ~/code/ruby/rails/rails3projects/"
```

This is the error message:

```
cd:cd:10: no such file or directory: /home/jryan/code/ruby/rails/rails3tutorial/
```

I don't know if the `cd:cd:10` means anything that should be a clue, but I am just starting to use `zsh` so I'm at a loss. If the command should work as I have it in this post that I'm sure it probably has something to do with another config file conflicting or something like that.

Comment: It looks like you've redefined `cd` as a function (probably by mistake). What does `type cd` show?

Comment: avoid this in the alias using \cd or 'builtin cd'

Answer (score 1):

Try defining a **function** instead of an **alias**:

```
function rubydev3 {
    builtin cd ~/code/ruby/rails/rails3projects/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the error message issued when you try to use the alias or during the processing of `~/.zshrc`? I notice that the error message has a different directory than the alias. Try this command:

```
type -a rubydev3
```

It will show you how "rubydev3" is defined.

It's possible that it's getting redefined.

Also, it's possible that `cd` has been aliased and that's interfering. To fix that, use this:

```
alias rubydev3="builtin cd ~/code/ruby/rails/rails3projects/"
```

Answer (score 0):

On the off chance - Are you using rvm? This adds functionality to cd, try turning it off.

```
export rvm_project_rvmrc=0
```